What to say if interviewed or detained by the police (UK)?
I have heard that you should refuse to answer questions from the police in case they misunderstand or misquote you. But doesn't that come over as rude? Wouldn't it be better to cooperate to some extent? I am innocent of what they might accuse me of, but it's a long story to explain why. I wouldn't want to go into detail straightaway, but on the other hand, if they asked me "Did you do/were you involved in X?" I would maybe sound guilty if I said "I'm not answering any questions". Surely it would be better to say "No I didn't, but I don't want to go into detail" or possibly "No I didn't because (a short, quick reason) but I don't want to go into detail"?
By the way, I can't afford a lawyer, if it gets to that stage...


Your question risks being closed because it seems you're asking for legal advice about real circumstances, which is off-topic here. Try rewording it as a hypothetical or more general question. 2. What is best to do in specific circumstances depends on those circumstances. 3. If you're arrested the police must tell you how you can access free legal advice (a duty solicitor or helpline depending on the alleged offence). 4. Try searching solicitors' websites for general guidance about police questions.


If you’re being interviewed by the police, you can’t afford to not have a lawyer. Police love unrepresented interviewees - they get to close so many of their open cases by pinning them on that person. The police are not on your side - whatever side you happen to be on, they’re on a different side.

In the US exercising your right to remain silent is free.

If you do speak, don't say anything more than you were asked. When asked "Did you do/were you involved in X?" the answer is "No", not a load of excuses – that is what can make you sound guilty, and they will do their best to unravel anything you've said, and are experts at confusing you: the 'verbals'.

A criminal case progresses from the police, to the CPS, to the trial itself. A legal tactic to optimize the outcome of a possible trial may increase the time an innocent "person of interest" stays a suspect of the investigation. Being convicted because of something stupid one said tends to more be serious than being investigated because of something one stupidly did not say, so it makes sense to err on the side of shutting up. But if you are sure you are technically (not just morally) innocent, and if you have information to resolve the case, can you look in the mirror if you keep quiet?

Re "doesn't that come over as rude?" No. In UK the police caution is "You do not have to say anything. But it may harm your defence if you do not mention when questioned something which you later rely on in court. Anything you do say may be given in evidence."

In the UK you have a right to a lawyer during police interviews regardless of your ability to pay. One will be provided if you ask, and there are prominent signs in the custody suite advising suspects of this.

" The police are not on your side - whatever side you happen to be on, they’re on a different side. –" So is it a kind of sport for them, to get as many people convicted as possible? Is there any financial incentive involved? Doesn't it sometimes work the other way - if we just let this bloke go, it'll be less work for us and more time to sit around drinking coffee (?)

@shawn22: Even if you are the victim of a crime the police are probably not on your side, if you are not the victim then they almost certainly are at best neutral to your fate.
This is inherent to any society, we live in a resource constrained system and simply can’t afford to randomly devote resources to optimizing the life of random people.
It’s not malicious, instead it’s quite simple, ignoring corrupt cops and their bruised egos, their job is law enforcement not “Help Shawn”. Not being corrupt actually works against you — they want you punished for whatever you can be.

I don't expect them to like me or feel sorry for me, but I would expect a fellow human being to listen carefully to what I had to say, record it faithfully, and then make an informed decision about whether or not to proceed with the case. But it seems that's too much to expect as well...

@shawn22 The police are supposed to investigate without fear or favour. I don't think they would be doing their jobs properly if a response such as, "No, I didn't do it but I don't want to go into detail," were sufficient to persuade them to move on to someone or something else.
